# Close window after triggering touch event angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic mobile application; when i click on a word, its description pops up beneath it, as shown here.

[image]

What I want to do is close the pop up whenever I slide the text or click anywhere on the page. 
Is this doable in AngularJs? if yes, What should I use?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a invisible full screen layer behind the popup, on clicking which you can hide both description as well as invisible layer and show rest.

Check out this codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOpXQw

> HTML

```
<html>
  <body ng-app>
    <div id="main" ng-app ng-controller="appController">
            <input type="button" ng-value="value1"  />
            <div id="invisible" ng-click="click()" ng-hide="hide">  </div>
    <input type="button" ng-value="value" ng-hide="hide" />


</div>

 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body{
    font:15px/1.3 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #5e5b64;
    text-align:center;
}

#main{
    height:1000px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
input
{
    margin-top:100px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    position:absolute;
}
#invisible
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

> JS

```
function appController($scope){
    $scope.value = 'Some Value from Scope';
    $scope.value1 = 'another Value from Scope';
    $scope.click = function()
    {
        $scope.hide=true;
        alert("outside was clicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use it directly without adding another layer? I have too many pop ups in the same class.. What are these values refer to?

Comment: How will you know that user has clicked outside ? There should be something to catch them. I didn't get your second line, elaborate please. Also that layer won't have nearly zero impact on your other elements.

Comment: I meant I have many pop ups under the same class="items". If anyone is open, clicking anywhere will close it. So in the js side i need to refer to the whole class. I really dont understand why you created two buttons

Comment: You can have any number of button with same class. Second button is to just show that first button is removed. Nothing special about that.

Comment: You still don't understand the problem:               <div ><font class="boxed" ng-show="collapsed"size="4" >I am description</font></div></div>
how will i close "boxed" after clicking on the invisible button (js side)?